# Cron is running but not saving entity

Tags: 8, entities, cron

I am trying to create a simple hook_cron to connect with an external API, return some data and update some fields in some entities. I'm creating like this to understand better how cron works, so I will upgrade it later to a queue.

The problem is that the cron is running, but even without errors the entity is not saving or updating. If I copy the code and try to execute it with a route (not using cron), it works as intended. I really don't know what is the problem with it.

I thank you for your help.

The code below:

```
function correios_web_service_cron()
{
    $trackingService = \Drupal::service('correios_web_service.tracking');
    $eventService = \Drupal::service('correios_web_service.event');

    $error = null;

    try {
        $order_ids = \Drupal::entityQuery('commerce_order')
            ->condition('type', 'campaign') //! Ver se terá que mudar o tipo
            ->condition('state', $eventService->getStatusByAlias('entregue')['description'], '<>')
            ->condition('state', $eventService->getStatusByAlias('avaliado')['description'], '<>')
            ->condition('state', $eventService->getStatusByAlias('cancelado')['description'], '<>')
            ->condition('field_tracking_code', NULL, '<>')
            ->execute();

        $Orders = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->loadMultiple($order_ids);
    }
    catch (\Throwable $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }

    if (empty($error) && !empty($Orders)) {
        foreach ($Orders as $Order) {
            $tracking_code = $Order->get('field_tracking_code')->value;

            try {
                $response = $trackingService->trackObjectFormatted($tracking_code);

                $Order->set('state', $response['description']);
                $Order->set('field_tracking_event_code', $response['event_code']);
                $Order->set('field_tracking_event_message', $response['event_message']);
                $Order->set('field_tracking_delivery_date', $response['delivery_date']);

                $Order->save();
            }
            catch (\Throwable $e) {
                \Drupal::logger('correios_web_service_cron')->error($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (!empty($error)) {
        \Drupal::logger('correios_web_service_cron')->error($error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing some tests I figured that somehow when executing the Query in cron it is not returning any data, but when executing the same query outside of cron it returns data. Someone know what is this?

Comment: Sounds like a permissions issue to me. Consider that cron is not necessarily running things as a logged in user as when you're using a Controller. In a similar circumstance, I actually put my code in a Controller and have cron invoke it.

Comment: thank you for the comment, I will try to use the query in a Controller.